# Why an eigenvector exists iff $\operatorname{det} (A-\lambda I) = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

I read some book which says:

$$A\vec{v} = \lambda\vec{v}  \iff (A-\lambda I)\vec{v} = 0$$

and it claims such a vector $\vec{v}$ exists iff $(A-\lambda I)\vec{v}$ is singular which means $\operatorname{det}(A-\lambda I) = 0$

Comment: It's bog-standard that $Bx=0$ has a nonzero solution if and only if $\det B=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson how can one show that?

Comment: By using elementary row operations to reduce to row-echelon form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition: a **non-zero** vector $\,v\,$ is an eigenvector of $\,A\,$ iff

$$Av=\lambda v\,\,\,,\,\,\lambda\in\Bbb F\Longleftrightarrow (A-\lambda I)v=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

the operator (or matrix) $A-\lambda I\,$ is singular as

$$\,0\neq v\in\ker A-\lambda I\Longrightarrow \ker (A-\lambda I)\neq\{0\}\Longleftrightarrow \det(A-\lambda I)=0$$

Comment: According to the invertible matrix theorem, "$B$ is invertible" $\Leftrightarrow$  $ker(B)=\{ \vec{0} \}$  $\Leftrightarrow$  $det(B)\neq 0$. Let $B=A-\lambda I$. For a complete proof, find the proof of the invertible matrix theorem.

Answer (score 5):

When $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$ it means there exists an $v\neq 0$ so that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$, 
if not, $(A-\lambda I)$ would be injective and hence bijective, so $\det (A-\lambda I)\neq 0$.

So we know $$(A-\lambda I) v= A v - \lambda v=0 \iff Av=\lambda v$$

On the other hand if $Av=\lambda v$ with $v\neq 0$ you know that 
$$(A-\lambda I)v=0$$
and hence the kernel isn't trivial, so $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$